# Trouble with first commit to git repository

Tags: git, github, terminal, commit, git-commit

I'm new to Git, and have set it up and created my first repository. I'm trying to add a README as the first commit, and I've been following the steps on http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/ exactly, but I get stuck on this step:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: username/Hello-World.git doesn't exist. Did you enter it correctly?
```

I think it is because I got the `git remote add` command wrong: I forgot to substitute my username and repository name. Retrying it with the correct arguments gives me:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:christineh/Hello-World.git
 fatal: remote origin already exists.
$ git push -u origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/christinehorvat/.ssh/id_rsa':
 ERROR: username/Hello-World.git doesn't exist. Did you enter it correctly?
 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly'
```

How can I clean this up and get the correct remote?

Comment: You did replace your username and git repo name in the `git remote add` command, didn't you?

Comment: Do you have a GitHub account?  I followed the steps at `http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/` and created a repository on GitHub called Hello-World.  The remote setting command GitHub prompts me to use on my local machine is `git remote add origin git@github.com:srivaths/Hello-World.git`.  Observe that there is no "username" in it.

Comment: @Sri Sankaran - here is what I get when I enter this command: $ git remote add origin git@github.com:christineh/Hello-World.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

Comment: @Mat I did- here is what happened when I tried again:  Christine-Horvats-MacBook-Pro-2:Hello-World christinehorvat$ git remote add origin git@github.com:christineh/Hello-World.git  
fatal: remote origin already exists.  
Christine-Horvats-MacBook-Pro-2:Hello-World christinehorvat$ git push -u origin master  
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/christinehorvat/.ssh/id_rsa':   
ERROR: username/Hello-World.git doesn't exist. Did you enter it correctly?  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly'

Comment: @ChristineHorvat: try `git remote rm origin`, then restart the `git remote add origin`, making sure you type your github username and repo name exactly.

Comment: Even if you find a solution to your own problem, or someone posts it in a comment, you should post it as an "answer" and accept it, rather than adding it to your question as an edit. That way, it does not keep appearing in the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You simply need to remove the `origin` remote that has the incorrect reference with:

```
$ git remote rm origin
```

Then restart the add, and push, and you should be good to go.

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:christineh/Hello-World.git
$ git push -u origin master
```